# How can I create a TABLE if and only if it does not exist?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",
                           user = "username",
                           passwd = "password",
                           db = "my_db")
cursor = conn.cursor ()
q = """IF NOT EXISTS CREATE TABLE %s (
         course  VARCHAR(15),
         student  VARCHAR(15),
         teacher VARCHAR(15),
         timeslot VARCHAR(15))""" % (d,)

cursor.execute(q)
```

But I get the error : `_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS CREATE TABLE ACCOUNTG (\\n\\t         course  VARCHAR(15),\\n\\t         s' at line 1")`

I'm not sure what's wrong with what I'm trying, I just want to make a table if it doesn't exist. Any input would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Wrong syntax: `IF NOT EXISTS CREATE TABLE` is not valid SQL in MySQL.

You want

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [tablename]
```

per the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html).